# can we resize an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

can we resize an array in java? if not, explain this:

```
    int arr[] = new int[1];
    arr[0]=-10;
    //arr[1]=1;
    arr=new int[2];  //Explain this
    arr[0]=-1;
    arr[1]=1;
    System.out.println(arr[0]+" "+arr[1]);
```

Comment: `reassign` != `resize`.

Comment: That's creating and assigning a new array, not resizing an array.

Comment: SO is not a beginner-tutorial on Java. I'd recommend you read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resizing an array is impossible, as far as I'm concerned.

To understand why your code works, you need to understand that arrays are reference types. `arr` holds an reference to the actual array, like this:

```
      holds                points to
arr ----------> reference -----------> array object
```

In this line:

```
arr=new int[2];
```

You are not doing anything to the array object at the very end there. You're basically saying:

> Hey `arr`. I don't want you to hold *that* reference anymore. Let go and hold *this* reference (which is an array with length 2)!

"What happens to the original array object with length 1 then?" you asked. This is where the GC comes into place. At some point, objects that has no reference pointing to, are collected.

Comment: Thank for explaining....

Comment: @SuprakashPal If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!